# Apache Ant build.xml: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details

Tags: apache, intellij-idea, ant

Please help, errors occur when I run build with ant, and I'm new to **apache ant**.

My project composes of two modules, this `build.xml` is my main project build file, and dependency module is set within the path label.

My `build.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project name="GameServer" basedir=".">
    <property name="build.dir" value="bin" />
    <property name="lib.dir" value="lib" />
    <property name="dist.dir" value="dist" />
    <property name="source.dir" value="src" />
    <property name="web.dir" value="WebContent" />
    <property name="TODAY" value="2019-09-10"/>

    <path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
        <path location="D:\backend\worldAndBattle\trunk\worldAndBattle" />
    </path>

    <!-- 初始化 -->
    <target name="init" description="Prepare for build">
        <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
    </target>

    <!-- 清理 -->
    <target name="clean" description="Clean all build products">
        <delete dir="${dist.dir}" quiet="true"/>
        <delete dir="${build.dir}" quiet="true"/>
    </target>

    <!-- 编译代码 -->
    <target name="compile" description="Compile application" depends="clean, init">
        <javac srcdir="${source.dir}" 
            destdir="${build.dir}" 
            includes="**/*.java" 
            debug="on" 
            deprecation="on" 
            source="1.7"
            includeAntRuntime="false">
            <classpath refid="classpath" />
        </javac>
    </target>

    <!-- 打包sql -->
    <target name="sql">
        <jar destfile="${build.dir}/sql.jar">
            <fileset dir="${source.dir}"
                includes="**/sql.xml,
                        **/*.properties"
            />
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Author" value="${user.name}" />
                <attribute name="Implementation-Date" value="${TODAY}" />
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>

    <!-- 打包game -->
    <target name="game" depends="compile, sql" >
        <jar destfile="${dist.dir}/game.jar">
            <fileset dir="${build.dir}" 
                includes="**/*"
                excludes="com/bianfeng/game/hotswap/*,
                          **/*Test.class,
                          **/Foo.class, 
                          **/applicationContext.xml, **/*.js, log4j.properties, logback.xml, conf.xml,
                          **/sql.xml"
            />
            <fileset dir="${source.dir}"
                     includes="**/*.properties"
            />
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Author" value="${user.name}" />
                <attribute name="Implementation-Date" value="${TODAY}" />
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.bianfeng.game.Main" />
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>

    <!-- 打包game -->
        <target name="game-with-application" depends="compile, sql" >
            <jar destfile="${dist.dir}/game.jar">
                <fileset dir="${build.dir}" 
                    includes="**/*"
                    excludes="com/bianfeng/game/hotswap/*,
                              **/*Test.class,
                              **/Foo.class, 
                              **/*.js, log4j.properties, logback.xml, conf.xml,
                              **/sql.xml"
                />
                <manifest>
                    <attribute name="Author" value="${user.name}" />
                    <attribute name="Implementation-Date" value="${TODAY}" />
                </manifest>
            </jar>
        </target>

    <target name="game-cross" depends="compile, sql" >
        <jar destfile="${dist.dir}/game-cross.jar">
            <fileset dir="${build.dir}"
                     includes="**/*"
                     excludes="**/*Test.class,
                              **/Foo.class,
                              **/*.js, log4j.properties, logback.xml, conf.xml,
                              **/sql.xml,
                              **/*Action.class,
                              **/*Dao.class
                     "
            />
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Author" value="${user.name}" />
                <attribute name="Implementation-Date" value="${TODAY}" />
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>
</project>
```

and, I am attaching an image with my [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kZQo.png).

> When I run compile, I get errors. And I don't know what should I do?

Comment: Did you change your project directory at some point? The error screenshot you posted shows your build being located in `D:\backend\game\trunk\game` but in your Ant script the classpath is set to `D:\backend\worldAndBattle\trunk\worldAndBattle`.

Comment: Sorry, this path "D:\backend\worldAndBattle\trunk\worldAndBattle" is a dependency of my main project, in other words, I need compile my project named game, but it depends another project, path is "D:\backend\worldAndBattle\trunk\worldAndBattle".